# Andengine Collisions - exception when detecting collisions and deleting bodies

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm working on a andengine powered box2d game. When I try to delete collided bodies from the scene some times following error occurs. Seems like it is a random error.

```
Uncaught handler: thread GLThread exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 48, size is 48
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:341)
at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:835)
at org.anddev.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.onManagedDraw(Shape.java:105)
at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:719)
at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onManagedDraw(Entity.java:835)
at org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onManagedDraw(Scene.java:271)
at org.anddev.andengine.entity.Entity.onDraw(Entity.java:719)
at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawScene(Engine.java:507)
at org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:499)
at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView$Renderer.onDrawFrame(RenderSurfaceView.java:148)
at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:617)
at org.anddev.andengine.opengl.view.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:549)
```

---

Following is my Update code block:

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler(){

            public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                scoreA = "SCORE  : "+p1score;
                hudTxtScoreA.setText(scoreA);
                scoreB = "SCORE  : "+p2score;
                hudTxtScoreB.setText(scoreB);
                if(p1score==900)
                {
                    hudTxtScoreA.setText("won");
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {



                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GmailGame.this);
                            builder.setMessage(playerA+" won the game !!!")
                                   .setCancelable(false)
                                   .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                           startActivity(new Intent(GmailGame.this, JoinGame.class));
                                           GlobalClass.setPartner("");

                                       }
                                   });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });

                    //mEngine.stop();
                }
                else if(p2score==900)
                {
                    hudTxtScoreB.setText("won");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {



                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(GmailGame.this);
                            builder.setMessage(playerB+" won the game !!!")
                                   .setCancelable(false)
                                   .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                           startActivity(new Intent(GmailGame.this, JoinGame.class));
                                           GlobalClass.setPartner("");

                                       }
                                   });
                            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                            alert.show();
                        }
                    });

                    //mEngine.stop();
                }

                if(x1!=null)
                {   
                    if(status.equals("1")){
                        isMyTurn=true;
                        status="0";
                    }



                if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("cat1"))||(x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("cat1"))){
                    if(icat1==0){
                        icat1=1;
                Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bcat1);
                scene.getLastChild().detachChild(scat1);


                p1score=p1score+100;
                //scene.detachChild(scat1);

                if(isMyTurn)
                sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");

                    }

                }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("cat2"))||x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("cat2")){
                    if(icat2==0){
                        icat2=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bcat2);   
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(scat2);
                    p1score=p1score+100;
                    p1win=p1win+1;
                    //scene.detachChild(scat2);

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");

                    }
                    }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("dog1"))||(x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("dog1"))){
                    if(idog1==0)
                    {
                        idog1=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bdog1);
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(sdog1);
                    //scene.detachChild(sdog1);
                    p1score=p1score+200;
                    p1win=p1win+1;

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");

                    }
                    }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("dog2"))||x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("dog2")){
                    if(idog2==0){
                        idog2=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bdog2);   
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(sdog2);
                    //scene.detachChild(sdog2);
                    p1score=p1score+200;
                    p1win=p1win+1;

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");
                }
                    }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("dog3"))||x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("dog3")){
                    if(idog3==0){
                        idog3=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bdog3);
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(sdog3);
                    //scene.detachChild(sdog2);
                    p1score=p1score+300;
                    p1win=p1win+1;

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");
                }
                    }
                if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("ecat1"))||(x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("ecat1"))){
                    if(iecat1==0){
                        iecat1=1;
                Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(becat1);
                scene.getLastChild().detachChild(secat1);
                p2score=p2score+100;
                p2win=p2win+1;
                //scene.detachChild(scat1);

                if(isMyTurn)
                sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");

                    }

                }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("ecat2"))||x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("ecat2")){
                    if(iecat2==0){
                        iecat2=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(becat2);  
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(secat2);
                    p2score=p2score+100;
                    p2win=p2win+1;
                    //scene.detachChild(scat2);

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");

                    }
                    }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("edog1"))||(x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("edog1"))){
                    if(iedog1==0)
                    {
                        iedog1=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bedog1);
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(sedog1);
                    //scene.detachChild(sdog1);
                    p2score=p2score+200;
                    p2win=p2win+1;

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");

                    }
                    }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("edog2"))||x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("edog2")){
                    if(iedog2==0){
                        iedog2=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bedog2);  
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(sedog2);
                    //scene.detachChild(sdog2);
                    p2score=p2score+200;
                    p2win=p2win+1;

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");
                }
                    }
                else if((x1.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("edog3"))||x2.getBody().getUserData().toString().equals("edog3")){
                    if(iedog3==0){
                        iedog3=1;
                    Log.e("suchith", x1.getBody().getUserData().toString());

                    String x1String = x1.getBody().getUserData().toString();
                    String x2String = x2.getBody().getUserData().toString();

                    mPhysicsWorld.destroyBody(bedog3);
                    scene.getLastChild().detachChild(sedog3);
                    //scene.detachChild(sdog2);
                    p2score=p2score+300;
                    p2win=p2win+1;

                    if(isMyTurn)
                    sendMessage1(x1String,x2String,"body");
                }
                    }                   

                }           
                }
                catch(NullPointerException e)
                {
                    Log.e("Update","Null");
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                                            Log.e("Udate","Error");
                }
            }
            public void reset() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return scene;
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: where you are deleting things, you need to be sure that is done on the update thread - use runOnUpdateThread()

Answer (score 2):

You're removing the body on the UI Thread.  This means that when the scene is being drawn, it's trying to draw something that's not attached to the scene anymore and you get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.  If instead of runOnUiThread you use runOnUpdateThread, you shouldn't have the problem.